# How does the loss backpropagate through the convolutional layer in CNN during backpropagation?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

This maybe a tough and confusing (the subject itself is confusing) question.

I understand how forward pass works in a typical multi-layer CNN (with multiple convolution, pooling, and ReLU). How does the backward pass convolution work in CNN backpropagation? That is, loss is first calculated in the output layer and how does it (the loss) backpropagate through a convolution layer?

Comment: http://andrew.gibiansky.com/blog/machine-learning/convolutional-neural-networks/#Backward-Propagation

Answer (score 1):

I agree **Backpropagation in CNN** is difficult and generally people use frameworks for CNN without even knowing the working. You can get intuition of Backprop from this [blog](https://becominghuman.ai/back-propagation-in-convolutional-neural-networks-intuition-and-code-714ef1c38199). The author has also given reference to several other blogs to delve deeper into its mathematics.